# How do I create multiple tags when a button is clicked? How do I make them disappear when there is too many of them?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div and inside it I am creating paragraph tags and this acts as a log for what is done on the website (like message shown when an action is done). Currently I have two buttons which use the same function to send the messages. However, I want one button to be on a cooldown and send a message when its clicked and when the cooldown is up. The second button stays like it is tho.

I also want the paragraph tags to be removed when a certain number of them is created (like when there is more than 10, the last one is removed).

Here's what I have:

```js
var credits = 0;
var clickPower = 1;

function addCred() {
  credits = credits + clickPower;
  document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML = credits + " Skatts";
};

function addLog(logBefore, logAfter) {
  var par = document.createElement("p");
  var node1 = document.createTextNode(logBefore);
  var node2 = document.createTextNode(logAfter);
  par.appendChild(node1);

  var element = document.getElementById("logs");
  element.appendChild(par);
};
```

```css
#logs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#logs p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="credits"></div>
<button onclick="addLog('Hunt begun', 'Hunt successful! You now have ' + credits + ' Skatts'); addCred();">HUNT</button>
<br>
<button onclick="addLog('Resources sold')">SELL</button>
<div id="logs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var credits = 0;
var clickPower = 1;

function addCred() {
  credits = credits + clickPower;
  document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML = credits + " Skatts";
};

function addLog(logBefore, logAfter) {
  var par = document.createElement("p");
  var node1 = document.createTextNode(logBefore);
  var node2 = document.createTextNode(logAfter);
  par.appendChild(node1);

  var element = document.getElementById("logs");
  // Here you can also use element.childNodes.length
  const count = document.getElementById("logs").getElementsByTagName("p").length;
  if(count >= 10){
      element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
  }
  element.appendChild(par);
};
```

```css
#logs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#logs p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="credits"></div>
<button onclick="addLog('Hunt begun', 'Hunt successful! You now have ' + credits + ' Skatts'); addCred();">HUNT</button>
<br>
<button onclick="addLog('Resources sold')">SELL</button>
<div id="logs"></div>
```

Comment: How do I change the opacity of the messages at the bottom?

Comment: @BeathanMann With Below Line you can change the opacity of the text to be deleted:
element.childNodes[0].style.opacity = "0.5";
Put this line in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I put the setTimeout() inside button Hunt. It starts countdown every time button Hunt been clicked. And when it done it says `Hunt successful! You now have ' + credits + ' Skatts')`. It's may not be like what you want yet. Because I still confused when you said  `when the cooldown is up. The second button stays like it is tho.`

```js
var credits = 0;
var clickPower = 1;

function addCred() {
  credits += clickPower;
  document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML = credits + " Skatts";
};

function addLog(logBefore, logAfter) {
  var par = document.createElement("p");
  var node1 = document.createTextNode(logBefore);
  var node2 = document.createTextNode(logAfter);
  par.appendChild(node1);

  var element = document.getElementById("logs");
  // Check if div logs has more than 10 childElement then delete it
  if (element.childElementCount >= 10) {
    element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
  }
  element.appendChild(par);
  //set cooldown when it done it say 
  setTimeout(function() {
    let credits = document.getElementById('credits').innerHTML;
    let whatToSay = 'Hunt successful! You now have ' + credits;
    let parForCooldown = document.createElement("p");
    if (element.childElementCount >= 10) {
      element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);
    }
    parForCooldown.appendChild(document.createTextNode(whatToSay));

    element.appendChild(parForCooldown);
  }, 3000);
};
```

```css
#logs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#logs p {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="credits"></div>
<button onclick="addLog('Hunt begun', 'Hunt successful! You now have ' + credits + ' Skatts'); addCred();">HUNT</button>
<br>
<button onclick="addLog('Resources sold')">SELL</button>
<div id="logs"></div>
```